# __CUDA_ARCH__ and kernel call in __host__ __device__ function

Tags: cuda

I came across a strange effect:

```
#define CUDA_ERR_CHECK(call) call

#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#if defined(__CUDACC__)

// Determine the size of type on device.
template<typename T>
__global__ void deviceSizeOf(size_t* result)
{
    *result = sizeof(T);
}

// Device memory aligned vector.
template<typename T>
class VectorDevice
{
    T* data;
    size_t size;
    int dim, dim_aligned;

public :
    __host__ __device__
    VectorDevice() : data(NULL), size(0), dim(0) { }

    __host__ __device__
    VectorDevice(int dim_) : data(NULL), size(0), dim(dim_)
    {
        dim_aligned = dim_;
        if (dim_ % AVX_VECTOR_SIZE)
            dim_aligned = dim + AVX_VECTOR_SIZE - dim_ % AVX_VECTOR_SIZE;
#if !defined(__CUDA_ARCH__)
        // Determine the size of target type.
        size_t size, *dSize;
        CUDA_ERR_CHECK(cudaMalloc(&dSize, sizeof(size_t)));
        deviceSizeOf<T><<<1, 1>>>(dSize);
        CUDA_ERR_CHECK(cudaGetLastError());
        CUDA_ERR_CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
        CUDA_ERR_CHECK(cudaMemcpy(&size, dSize, sizeof(size_t), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        CUDA_ERR_CHECK(cudaFree(dSize));

        // Make sure the size of type is the same on host and on device.
        if (size != sizeof(T))
        {
            std::cerr << "Unexpected unequal sizes of type T in VectorDevice<T> on host and device" << std::endl;
            exit(2);
        }
#endif
    }
};

#endif // __CUDACC__

int main()
{
    VectorDevice<int> v(10);

    return 0;
}
```

Here, a kernel is being called from the host version of `__host__ __device__` constructor. Surprisingly, when running this code it silently exits with code 1 from the kernel call wrapper:

```
(gdb) make
nvcc -arch=sm_30 test.cu -o test -DAVX_VECTOR_SIZE=32
(gdb) b exit
Breakpoint 1 at 0x7ffff711b1e0: file exit.c, line 104.
(gdb) r
Breakpoint 1, __GI_exit (status=1) at exit.c:104
104 exit.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) f 3
#3  0x0000000000402c36 in VectorDevice<int>::VectorDevice(int) ()
(gdb) f 2
#2  0x0000000000402cb0 in void deviceSizeOf<int>(unsigned long*) ()
(gdb) f 1
#1  0x0000000000402ad2 in void __wrapper__device_stub_deviceSizeOf<int>(unsigned long*&) ()
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function _Z35__wrapper__device_stub_deviceSizeOfIiEvRPm:
   0x0000000000402abc <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000402abd <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x0000000000402ac0 <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x0000000000402ac4 <+8>: mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x0000000000402ac8 <+12>:    mov    $0x1,%edi
   0x0000000000402acd <+17>:    callq  0x402270 <exit@plt>
End of assembler dump.
```

Further investigation reveals that the kernel code does not appear in cubin, and that `__CUDA_ARCH__` is somehow involved into this behavior.

So, 2 questions:

1) Why does this happen?

2) How to use `__CUDA_ARCH__` for conditional compilation of `__host__ __device__` code in combination with host-side kernel calls?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** The same example is shown in section E.2.2.1 item 2 of C programming guide. However, it's still unclear what is the proper way of handling this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Why does this happen?

It happens because you are stepping on [the specific restriction](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-arch-macro) you pointed to in the programming guide: the templated instantiation of `deviceSizeOf` for `<int>` must take place both when `__CUDA_ARCH__` is defined and when it is not defined.  If you use restricted forms, the behavior is undefined.

> 2) How to use `__CUDA_ARCH__` for conditional compilation of `__host__ __device__` code in combination with host-side kernel calls?

One possible approach would be to force the instantiation of the kernel function for type `<int>` regardless of the `__CUDA_ARCH__` macro.

You could do this by adding the following line immediately after your kernel template definition:

```
template __global__ void deviceSizeOf<int>(size_t *);
```

When I add that line after your kernel definition, and provide a suitable definition for `AVX_VECTOR_SIZE` (which appears to be undefined in your example AFAICT), your code compiles and runs correctly for me.

Comment: Thanks, @Robert! Please review also my answer below, that does not use explicit template instantiation.

Comment: I haven't tried it, but it seems like your method should work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found it might be possible to resolve the issue without explicit template instantiation:

```
class VectorDevice
{
    T* data;
    size_t size;
    int dim, dim_aligned;

    struct A
    {
        __host__
        A()
        {
            bool neverCalled = true;
            if (!neverCalled)
            {
                deviceSizeOf<T><<<1, 1>>>(NULL);
                CUDA_ERR_CHECK(cudaGetLastError());
                CUDA_ERR_CHECK(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
            }
        }
    } a;

public :

    __host__ __device__
    VectorDevice() : data(NULL), size(0), dim(0) { }

    #pragma hd_warning_disable \
    #pragma nv_exec_check_disable
    __host__ __device__
    VectorDevice(int dim_) : data(NULL), size(0), dim(dim_)
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
};

...
```